# Why does OpenGL use 4 floats to define colour normally?

Tags: c, opengl

I am learning to use OpenGL and am surprised colour seems to be always defined as a `vec4` struct comprising of 4 single precision `float`ing point numbers. I am surprised because if the size of memory to be copied to the graphics memory is a concern (thats why indices exist with vertex shaders) the size of each colour is:

```
4 x 32 = 128 bits or 16 bytes
```

when all that is needed to define a 32 bit colour is 32 bits (4 bytes)! Why not define ARGB colour channels as bytes instead?

Comment: OpenGL also has `glColor3ub` which uses bytes for each component.

Comment: 128 bits is 16 bytes, not 32.

Comment: computergraphics.stackexchange . . .

Comment: In OpenGL you can specify colors with what precision you want. The spec is certainly not tied to 4 bytes per color channel.

Comment: Updated title to say normally, im sure there is a good reason, I am not looking to change it, I am just interested why..

Comment: Using floats allows for future developments. If you do a lot of image adjusting and compositing, 8 bits per channel isn't enough. Even a couple of decades ago TV and film people wanted more than 32 bit colour. The latest HDMI spec allows 10 bits per colour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> colour seems to be always defined as a vec4 struct comprising of 4 single precision floating point numbers

First: it's not.  When you load a texture, try using one of the sized formats as the internal format.  For example, GL_RGBA8 is a normalized format with 8-bits per-channel.  GL_RGBA16F is a 16-bit floating-point format per-channel.  There are lots.

The variety is provided for memory reasons, as you say, but also for algorithmic choices.  E.g. you can use texture views to read a single-channel integer texture as a 4-byte four-channel texture.  As another example, for single-pass depth peeling using 64-bit atomics, you can view a floating-point depth buffer as an atomic integer buffer.

---

As for vertex data, you again have your choice.  The API provides different strides and sizes into your data.  Internally, though, the format will almost always be converted into floating-point just before the shader runs.

Why?  Because all of the data is processed by a floating point processor anyway.  Everything you do--blending, texture modulation, BRDF modulation, etc.--is done in floating point.  This is fine; rendering is usually bound by fragment shader texture accesses, so floating-point compute is comparatively free.

Comment: makes sense, wouldn't want to be using `byte`s in maths calculations